# ExportAsFixedFormat method on Project

Tags: vba, ms-project, ms-office-script

I have got the next error when I try to use Subroutine. The error is:[image]

My code is:

```
Sub CreatePackages()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim matrix As Project
Dim template As Project
Dim templatePath As String
Dim selectedMatrix As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Assign active project to matrix object
Set matrix = Application.ActiveProject

'Check if a matrix file is selected
If matrix Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Failed to open the Matrix file.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'Select the folder where the packages will be saved
folderPath = SelectFolder()

'Activate the current project

'Check if a valid folder is selected
If folderPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No valid folder selected.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through all the tasks in the matrix
Dim ot As Task
Dim otIdentifier As Integer
Dim otNumber As String
Dim packagePath As String
Dim completePackagePath As String
Dim packageName As String
Dim planOfWorkName As String
Dim task As Task
Dim viewPTName As String
Dim newPackage As Project
Dim templateOpened As Boolean
Dim waitTime As Date

'Get the complete path of the template file
templatePath = folderPath & "\Template_PQ_2023.mpp"

For Each ot In matrix.Tasks
    If ot.Summary And ot.OutlineLevel = 2 Then

        'Open the template file
        templateOpened = Application.FileOpenEx(Name:=templatePath)
        
        'Initialize the template
        Set template = Application.ActiveProject
     
        'Check if the template opened successfully
        If template Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to open the template file.", vbCritical
            matrix.Close
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'Activate the matrix file
        matrix.Activate
        
        'Select the task
        otIdentifier = ot.ID
        SelectRow Row:=otIdentifier, RowRelative:=False
      
        'Copy the task to the matrix file
        Application.EditCopy
                    
        'Activate the template file
        template.Activate
        
        'Select the first row in the file
        SelectRow Row:=1, RowRelative:=False
        
        'Paste the task into the template
        Application.EditPaste
        
        'Get the task number
        otNumber = ot.Text4
        
        'Create a folder for the package
        packagePath = CreateFolder(otNumber, folderPath)
        
        'Create the package name *.mpp
        packageName = "PQ-" & otNumber
        
        'Create the complete package path for the *.mpp file
        completePackagePath = packagePath & Application.PathSeparator & packageName & ".mpp"
        
        'Save the package with the name "PQ-otNumber"
        template.SaveAs Name:=completePackagePath
        
        Set newPackage = Application.ActiveProject
        
        'Create the Plan of Work name
        planOfWorkName = packageName & "-PT"
        
        'Create the complete name for the Plan of Work including the full path
        viewPTName = packagePath & Application.PathSeparator & planOfWorkName & ".pdf"
        Debug.Print (viewPTName)
        
        'Export the Plan of Work view to PDF
        newPackage.ExportAsFixedFormat FileType:=pjPDF, FileName:=viewPTName, ArchiveFormat:=True
                
        'Create the Personnel Required name
        personnelRequiredName = packageName & "-PR"
        
        'Create the complete name for the Personnel Required including the full path
        viewPRName = packagePath & Application.PathSeparator & personnelRequiredName & ".pdf"
        Debug.Print (viewPRName)
                
        'Switch to the Personnel Required view
        SendKeys "{F10}", True
        SendKeys "{o}", True
        SendKeys "{w}", True
        SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
        
        'Export the Personnel Required view to PDF
        newPackage.ExportAsFixedFormat FileType:=pjPDF, FileName:=viewPRName, ArchiveFormat:=True

        
        Application.Quit
        
        
        'Close the new file
        'Application.FileCloseEx pjSave
                
    End If
Next ot

Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I try to create separate parts of a project from a complete project. But the main error here is that I can not use the ExporAsFixedFormat on order to save several views that are parts of my Job Packet. I expect that somebody can help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Which _ExportAsFixedFormat_ fails?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: Is _viewPRName_ a valid path/filename? Does the folder exist?

Comment: Yes, It does. I used Debug.Print to review it.